# Saving a CSV using CSVBuilderService?

Tags: java, file, csv

I created a CsvBuilderService

```
CSVBuilderService<Vector<Object>> builder = new CSVBuilderService<Vector<Object>>();
```

Then I created ByeArrayOutputStream:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream os = (ByteArrayOutputStream)builder.buildCsvToStream(tableDataMatrixTemp);
```

tableDataMatrixTemp is a `Vector< Object >`.

Now, how can I print that **>** on a CSV and saving the csv on a specified path? (I don't want to download the file from web, only save it to a path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = (ByteArrayOutputStream)builder.buildCsvToStream(tableDataMatrixTemp);
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your-filename-goes-here")) {
   os.writeTo(fos);
}
```

**Java 7+**

Answer (score 0):

**Below code snippet might help you !**

```
 public void writeCSV() {

            // Delimiter used in CSV file
            private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";

            // CSV file header
            private static final Object[] FILE_HEADER = { "Empoyee Name","Empoyee Code", "In Time", "Out Time", "Duration", "Is Working Day" };

            String fileName = "fileName.csv");
            List<Objects> objects = new ArrayList<Objects>();
            FileWriter fileWriter = null;
            CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter = null;

            // Create the CSVFormat object with "\n" as a record delimiter
            CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

            try {
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

                csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);

                csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

                // Write a new student object list to the CSV file
                for (Object object : objects) {
                    List<String> record = new ArrayList<String>();

                    record.add(object.getValue1().toString());
                    record.add(object.getValue2().toString());
                    record.add(object.getValue3().toString());

                    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(record);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fileWriter.flush();
                    fileWriter.close();
                    csvFilePrinter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```